# Why is my Ruby function web scraping the first page only and not the paginated pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, httparty

I am using nokogiri to web scrape all vehicles across about 14 pages in a dealership website, the bug I am encountering is my code is running the scraper 14 times on only the first page. What is wrong in my code?

As you can see from the output the same vehicles are being scraped over and over again instead of the new set of vehicles from the next page.

**Ruby version :** 2.6.2

**scraper.rb :**

```
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'httparty'
    require 'byebug'
    
    def scraper
        url = "https://www.example.com/new-vehicles/"
        unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
        parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
        vehicles = Array.new
        vehicle_listings = parsed_page.css("//div[@class='vehicle list-view new-vehicle publish']") #20 cars
        page = 1
        per_page = vehicle_listings.count  #20
        total = parsed_page.css('span.count').text.to_i #281
        last_page = (total.to_f / per_page.to_f).ceil #14
        while page <= last_page
            pagination_url = "https://www.example.com/new-vehicles/#action=im_ajax_call&perform=get_results&page=#{page}"
            pagination_unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(pagination_url)
            puts pagination_url
            puts "Page: #{page}"
            puts ''
            pagination_parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(pagination_unparsed_page)
            pagination_vehicle_listings = pagination_parsed_page.css("//div[@class='vehicle list-view new-vehicle publish']") #20 cars
            pagination_vehicle_listings.each do |vehicle_listing|
                vehicle = {
                    title: vehicle_listing.css('h2')&.text&.gsub("New", '').gsub("2021", '').gsub("With", '').gsub("Navigation", ''),
                    price: vehicle_listing.css('span.price')[0]&.text&.delete('^0-9').to_i,
                    stock_number: vehicle_listing.css('.stock-label')&.text.gsub("Stock #: ", ''),
                    exterior_color: vehicle_listing.css('span.detail-content')[3]&.text,
                    interior_color: vehicle_listing.css('span.detail-content')[4]&.text&.delete('0-9').gsub('MPG', 'unavailable')
                }
                vehicles << vehicle
                    puts "Added #{vehicle[:stock_number]}"
                    puts ""
                end
                page += 1
        end
    byebug
    end
        
scraper
```

**output :**

> Page: 1
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218864
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218865
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218604
>
> https://www.example.com/new-vehicles/#action=im_ajax_call&perform=get_results&page=2
>
> Page: 2
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218864
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218865
>
> Added vehicle with stock#:  218604

Comment: I don't think it is neccessary to provide that much output, perhaps you can clean it up a bit?

Comment: Please see: [mcve], with emphasis on the word **minimal**. It's great that you've included a complete/verifiable code sample, but did you really need to show **ALL** of this information in order to explain the problem? What does the code for `exterior_color: vehicle_listing.css('span.detail-content')...` have to do with it? Does showing us 12 pages of verbose debugging help explain it?

Comment: In other words, you could probably have explained this question with about 8 lines of code and less than 5% of the debug output.

Comment: Further to the answer below, I would say that this website is *unusually difficult* to scrape. The approach you've used above would work fine for the majority of websites. The problem here is that pagination is being done via jQuery / AJAX requests, rather than via regular query parameters in a GET request.

Comment: @Pascal sorry about the overkill output I reduced it in the question.

Comment: @TomLord sorry about the overkill output I reduced it in the question.

Comment: @TomLord i'd say they at least partly implemented it that way to make it difficult for scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to scrape the data I needed by using Watir and a headless chrome browser which allowed the ajax/javascript code to run before the page was scraped.

```
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'httparty'
    require 'byebug'
    require 'watir'
    
    def scraper
        url = "https://www.example.com/new-vehicles/"
        unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
        parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
        vehicles = Array.new
        vehicle_listings = parsed_page.css("//div[@class='vehicle list-view new-vehicle publish']") #20 cars
        page = 1
        per_page = vehicle_listings.count  #20
        total = parsed_page.css('span.count').text.to_i #281
        last_page = (total.to_f / per_page.to_f).ceil #14
        
        # Create instance of headless chrome called browser
        browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
        
        while page <= last_page
            pagination_url = "https://www.example.com/new-vehicles/#action=im_ajax_call&perform=get_results&page=#{page}"
            browser.goto(pagination_url)
            pagination_unparsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)
            puts pagination_url
            puts "Page: #{page}"
            puts ''
            pagination_parsed_page = pagination_unparsed_page
            pagination_vehicle_listings = pagination_parsed_page.css("//div[@class='vehicle list-view new-vehicle publish']") #20 cars
            pagination_vehicle_listings.each do |vehicle_listing|
                vehicle = {
                    stock_number: vehicle_listing.css('.stock-label')&.text.gsub("Stock #: ", '')
                }
                vehicles << vehicle
                    puts "Added #{vehicle[:stock_number]}"
                    puts ""
                end
                page += 1
        end
        # Be sure to close the browser
        browser.close
    byebug
    end

scraper
```

Answer (score 1):

While it might appear that the data is loaded via a GET request by following the link it is actually loaded via a POST request through jQuery.
You can verify this by opening the "network" tab of your browsers developer tools.

If you enter the url into your browser one request is made:

- a GET request for the initial content

If you then click a link in the pagination nav of the vehicles listing then

- URL is updated to contain the page. Note, it is not as *query* (`?`) but as part of the  *fragment* (`#`) which is never sent to the server but stays on the client.
- the content for the requested page is fetched via a POST request (through jQuery) and that response is then merged into the content and it looks like it has been fetched by following the link.

If you want to mimic this POST request, then it is a bit more complex:

It contains a *nonce* that you can find in the initial content (search for `ajax_nonce`) that ouy must send along (so get the initial content, scrape the nonce and then send it along with the POST requests)

Here is a sample with CURL (replace the nonce) that will reqturn the listings for page 2 as JSON (even though the response header says `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

```
curl -X POST https://www.pacificbmw.com/
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
     -d "action=im_ajax_call&perform=get_results&page=2&_nonce=e085e144a19b3b493c7aab9aff479722&_post_id=6&_referer=/new-vehicles/"
```

This will return

```
{"results":"
<table class=\ "results_table\">\n
    <tbody>\t\n\n
        <tr class=\ "hidden-xs\">\n
            <td colspan=\ "7\">\n
                <!-- VEHICLE BLOCK -->\n
                <div class=\ "vehicle list-view new
    ....
```

Which you will need to parse as JSON and then extract the `results` key and parse this again with nokogiri and then scrape the listings.

Update:

As an alternative you could also use a scraper that supports and executes javascript (Selenium + Headless Chrome or similar)

Like this you would mimik a browser and a user and you can trigger clicks form inputs.

This article is a short intro: https://russmorley.net/tutorial/selenium/2019/03/07/Scrape.html